# Ruler and compass constructions

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, geometric-construction

Please sketch a proof for the following therom :
If the point P is constructible from B, then the degree of the extension [ B(P) : B ] is some power of 2.

I have done a proof of this therom from the book Advanced abstract algebra by BHUPENDRA SINGH . But in this book the proof is given only for a special case where B(P) is considered as a field of real numbers and B is field of rationals.
I am confused somewhere this therom includes a point P of plane ,and the proof is for a real number .
Thanks.

Comment: It would be best if you can give some more definitions from your book. That would help clarify the presentation given in your book. The way I studied this from *Galois Theory* by David Cox is that all points of the plane are represented by complex numbers and if a point $P$ can be constructed using a finite number of well defined geometrical constructions starting with points $0,1$ then the complex number $\alpha$ corresponding to $P$ is called a constructible number.

Comment: And then it can be proved that $[\mathbb{Q} (\alpha) :\mathbb{Q}] $ is a power of $2$.

Comment: It should be noted that $\alpha $ is constructible if and only if its real and imaginary parts are constructible.